# How do group rows and indent tables ? From R to excel

Tags: r, excel, export-to-excel, data-wrangling, openxlsx

As input, I have a dataframe `df`. Once I export it to excel, I have `image 1` below. However, I need output as `image 2` in which the column 'sex' is aggregated with column `name`, and then the results are shown as "grouped by" sex. I hope that makes sense.

*PS: this dataframe is only an example. My real data is quite different, but it follows the same idea. As you may imagine, I have to use this specific format. It doesn't matter which packages or functions I use to achieve this. I have to update data like this very often, usually take quite some time. I'm trying to automatize this part of the process.*

## Input

```
library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)

df <- starwars %>% 
  select(name, height, mass, hair_color, skin_color, eye_color, sex) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(sex)) %>% 
  group_by(sex) %>% 
  slice_head(n = 3) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(sex, everything())

df %>% write.xlsx("df.xlsx")
```

## Image 1 - Current Output

[image]

## Image 2 - Expected Output

[image]

Comment: You may need to use packages like kable, formattable, etc

Answer (score 2):

With the assumption that no `name` is originally `NA` (not a concern for this dataset), we can capitalize on the fact that `NA` values will be written into the xlsx file as blanks, not the literal `NA` string.

```r
tmp <- df %>%
  group_by(sex) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(across(-sex, ~ .[NA])) %>%
  bind_rows(df) %>%
  arrange(sex, !is.na(name)) %>%
  mutate(`name by sex` = if_else(is.na(name), sex, paste("    ", name))) %>%
  select(-sex, -name) %>%
  relocate(`name by sex`)
tmp
# # A tibble: 14 x 6
#    `name by sex`                height  mass hair_color  skin_color       eye_color
#    <chr>                         <int> <dbl> <chr>       <chr>            <chr>    
#  1 "female"                         NA    NA NA          NA               NA       
#  2 "     Leia Organa"              150    49 brown       light            brown    
#  3 "     Beru Whitesun lars"       165    75 brown       light            blue     
#  4 "     Mon Mothma"               150    NA auburn      fair             blue     
#  5 "hermaphroditic"                 NA    NA NA          NA               NA       
#  6 "     Jabba Desilijic Tiure"    175  1358 NA          green-tan, brown orange   
#  7 "male"                           NA    NA NA          NA               NA       
#  8 "     Luke Skywalker"           172    77 blond       fair             blue     
#  9 "     Darth Vader"              202   136 none        white            yellow   
# 10 "     Owen Lars"                178   120 brown, grey light            blue     
# 11 "none"                           NA    NA NA          NA               NA       
# 12 "     C-3PO"                    167    75 NA          gold             yellow   
# 13 "     R2-D2"                     96    32 NA          white, blue      red      
# 14 "     R5-D4"                     97    32 NA          white, red       red
```

and then write that to your worksheet.

```r
openxlsx::write.xlsx(tmp, file = "df.xlsx")
```

[image: xlsx screenshow]

FYI, the use of `~ .[NA]` in the call to `across` is one way to verify that we get the "right" form of the `NA` object. There are at least six such types of `NA`, so for "formality" I prefer to always ensure we have the correct class. In this case, though, the `bind_rows(df)` in the pipe will then reconvert them to the original (non-`logical`) class, so it might seem unnecessary here. However, it works here because something else accidentally (?) fixed it, not because it was done correctly the first time. You can see what I mean by running

```r
df %>%
  group_by(sex) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(across(-sex, ~ NA))
# # A tibble: 4 x 7
#   sex            name  height mass  hair_color skin_color eye_color
#   <chr>          <lgl> <lgl>  <lgl> <lgl>      <lgl>      <lgl>    
# 1 female         NA    NA     NA    NA         NA         NA       
# 2 hermaphroditic NA    NA     NA    NA         NA         NA       
# 3 male           NA    NA     NA    NA         NA         NA       
# 4 none           NA    NA     NA    NA         NA         NA
```

where most of the columns are "lgl" (`logical`) class.

Comment: Ruam Pimentel, is this close?